# Off-Site push notification for desktop

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification, notifications, desktop

I want to develop Off-site push notification for my website.

Like, when I open my browser and instantly get the notification without open any website.

If someone visit my website and subscribe for notifications then after whenever he or she open browser then I want to send notification to that user.

Is it possible?

Please provide some link/resource so I can create that type of code.

Thanks...:)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for Push notifications :

Here are some links to read :

Demo : https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/

Data : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/

Service : https://onesignal.com/webpush

Comment: This is for Off-Site push notification?

Comment: Yes but user needs to subscribe to your notifications, but I'm not sure user will receive on browser start.

Comment: Data: push notification only for chrome.
Service: I already implemented this functionality - this is for on-site Notification.
Demo: It's not working on Firefox.

Comment: Yes, it is not supported in firefox, but you can use it on chrome without website opened. Test it with POSTMAN

Comment: Then if someone open Mozilla then what will happen?
Your given details works in Chrome apps and extensions. It's different from the Notifications API.